# how to ask re expression to do minimal match without starting from the beginning

Tags: regex

I want to match `A+B` in `A+C+A+B`, and I used expression like this:

```
A.+?B
```

However, the re expression above stills matches `A+C+A+B`, not `A+B`. It seems the search always starts from the beginning. Is there any way to prevent this?

EDIT: I am just showing a minimal working example, the actual string may be `AAA (blabla without AAA or BBB) CCC AAA (balbla without AAA or BBB) BBB` and I want to match `AAA (balbla without AAA or BBB) BBB`.

EDIT: To be more clear, I want all matches in a string that cannot contain sub-matches. As stated before: `A.+?B` matches 'A+C+A+B', but `A+C+A+B` contains a sub-match, namely `A+B`. So that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use look-arounds to make sure we do not capture `AAA`, nor `BBB` on our path to `BBB`:

```
AAA(?:(?!AAA|BBB).)*BBB
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT7cM7/5) (we can also add word boundaries in case `AAA` and `BBB` are words - `\bAAA\b(?:(?!\b(?:AAA|BBB)\b).)*\bBBB\b`).

Comment: I am just showing a minimal working example. I don't mean that the processing string is actually joined by `+`.

Comment: I think he also wants to match A-B if present

Comment: What is the real-life example?

Comment: I really don't mean this, I will edit the question again in a minute.

Comment: I hope my updated answer is clear enough. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I think your last edit works for me, but I just thought minimal match should have the feather I stated in my second edit, or it should not be called minimal match.

Comment: Sorry, I was misled by the initial example in the beginning (+1)

Comment: So is there a general way to realize the feature in my second edit?

Comment: Do you mean something like `(?!.*AAA\+BBB)AAA(?:(?!AAA|BBB).)*BBB` ? Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD5iH0/3) where I am using a negative look-ahead as a condition to exclude matches if we have just `AAA+BBB` in the match.